# Best way to input age range with over and under

Tags: jquery, forms, input

This is a very simple question, but I'm drawing a blank.

I need to add an age range input to my form (as in create buckets of age ranges that can be selected by people later in a survey let's say).

As an example, the inputs can be the following

Under 50
50-55
55-59
60 and Over

What's the best way to let the admin ranges like that?  The 50-55 is obviously straight forward just two text boxes.  But how would they enter Under 50?  Do I have to make them leave the first box blank and enter 49 in the second box?  And for 60 and over enter 60 and leave the second text box blank?  There must be a better way.

Comment: If you have equal sized groups you can go for three values: `min-age`, `max-age`, `age-step`

Comment: I would simplify it and just use a single select element with values like "Under 50", "50-55", etc.

Comment: As far as I understand the question the OP want a configurable select box, which defines a select for possible participants in the survey. Not predefined ranges.

Answer (score 0):

How about just a dropdown list instead of two text boxes?

```
<select>
   <option>under 50</option>
   <option>50 to 60</option>
   <option>over 60</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As far as I understand the question the OP want a configurable select box, which later on generates this HTML based upon the (admin) user input.

Answer (score 0):

you should propose a choice to user for example a Drop Down List something like:

```
          <select id="Select1">
                <option value="0">Under 50</option>
                <option value="1">50-55</option>
                <option value="2">55-59</option>
                <option value="3">60 and Over</option>

            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this just as you suggest:

- two text inputs to define each bucket
- leaving first blank means <= second (they could also enter 0 in first field)
- leaving second blank means > first

You would have to do some validation to ensure the ranges do not overlap.

Another approach would be to just allow the boundary values to be specified as a comma-delimited list in one text field:

i.e. 50, 55, 60 would translate to 4 categories: 50 or under, 51-55, 56-60, over 60

I think this solution is more elegant but would be harder for user to understand.